# Need to create a formula for points distribution in the game

Tags: arithmetic, applications

There is the following data for a simple game:

- 3 players
- General points pool - 30000
- Each player has a force. Initial force value - 100
- During the game force indicator is changing. Min value of force - 1, max value - 299
- With minimal force - 1, player gets the minimum points amount - 5000 per round. The rest of the points pool is evenly dividing between other players.

We certainly know the result in 2 cases:
1) If the force is 1, player gets 5000 points
2) If the force is 100 (initial value) - player gets 10000 points.

Total pool of points is always 30000

Help to find a formula to dynamically calculate the distribution of points for different values of force.